# Java Compound Interest Calculator

Tags: java

I am currently working on a Java compound interest calculator. I am extremely new to Java and this project has been very challenging and I now find myself at a brick wall.

I fear I am doing something fundamentally wrong that I should know (did I put something in the wrong place?)

I get an 'illegal start of type' error next to my line:

```
for ( int i = 0; i<period; i++)
```

I think I may need to place this inside a method? Here's my full code.

Account.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Account extends JFrame {

private int period;
private int balance;
private int rate;
private String printstring;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Period: " + period + ", Balance: " + balance);
}

public int getPeriod() {
    return period;
}

public void setPeriod(int period) {
    this.period = period;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public int getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(int rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public String getPrintstring() {
    return printstring;
}

public void setPrintString(String printstring) {
    this.printstring = printstring;
}


for ( int i = 0; i<period; i++)
{
    balance = (balance * rate) + balance;
}
}
```

Banker.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Banker {

private static final int H = 400;       // Height of window pixels
private static final int W = 500;       // Width  of window pixels

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String period;
    String balance;
    String rate;

    period = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Interest period:");
    balance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Current balance:");
    rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Interest rate:");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Savings Interest Calculator");
    JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
    JLabel blabel = new JLabel("Period: " + period);
    JLabel plabel = new JLabel("Balance: " + balance);
    JLabel flabel = new JLabel("Balance: " + balance);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(calculate);
    frame.add(plabel);
    frame.add(blabel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

Comment: The for loop needs to be inside a method.

Comment: You can just calculate compound interest, no loop required. http://qrc.depaul.edu/StudyGuide2009/Notes/Savings%20Accounts/Compound%20Interest.htm

Answer (score 0):

you have to write

```
 for ( int i = 0; i<period; i++)
{
    balance = (balance * rate) + balance;
}
```

inside a method body. you cant write such statements out side your methods.try to write it inside a method body like below.

```
public void myMethod() {
     for ( int i = 0; i<period; i++)
    {
        balance = (balance * rate) + balance;
    }

}
```